# Undergrad Analysis problem

Tags: real-analysis

Let function $f$ be continuous real function on $\Bbb R$.
Let sequence $\{x_n \}$ be defined by 
$x_1\in\Bbb R, x_{n+1}=f(x_n) (n=1,2,...)$

If $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=\ell \in\Bbb R$, and $f'(\ell)$ exists, prove that $|f'(\ell)|\le1$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Can you share what you've tried and what you're having trouble with? Do you have any techniques or approaches you think might be relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^2$ and $x_1=1$, then $x_n=1\,\forall n $. And $f'(1)=2.$

Comment: Indeed, we need to have $x_n \to \ell$ but $x_n \neq \ell$ along the way for this to work. A less trivial example is one where the fixed point is mapped to in some finite but nonzero number of steps. A family of examples of this type is $f(x)=a(x-x^2),|a|>1,x_1=1$.

Comment: @ian you can also find examples where you hit the fixed point after exactly $m$ steps as well.

Comment: Are you disproving the theorem with a counter example ?

Comment: Maybe some assumption is omitted...sorry